# Dismiss multiple dialogs at once inside a timer methord

Tags: android, android-dialog

Four alertDialog boxes are appearing at the same time, i want all of them to be removed at the same time when a timer method is encountered.  What should i do?

```
 AlertDialog.Builder mainBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AdminViewActivity.this);
                                mainBuilder.setMessage("Table No " +TableList.get(i)+" At Time "+TimeList.get(i))
                               .setPositiveButton("Waiter Called", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                                {
                                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                       dailog1=dialog;
                                       dialog.dismiss();       
                                   }
                                });
                                AlertDialog mainAlert = mainBuilder.create();
                                mainAlert.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams WMLP = mainAlert.getWindow().getAttributes();
                                mainAlert.getWindow().getAttributes().gravity = Gravity.LEFT|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
                                WMLP.x = 10;   //x position
                                WMLP.y = 300;   //y position
                                mainAlert.getWindow().setAttributes(WMLP);
                                mainAlert.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save a reference to all Dialogs and then simply dismiss it:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Dialog mDialog1;
    Dialog mDialog2;
    Dialog mDialog3;
    Dialog mDialog4;

    public void someAction() {
        mDialog1.dismiss();
        mDialog2.dismiss();
        mDialog3.dismiss();
        mDialog4.dismiss();
    }

    public void somewhere() {
        mDialog1 = new dialog();
        mDialog2 = new dialog();
        mDialog3 = new dialog();
        mDialog4 = new dialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: dialog1
dialog2
dialog3
dialog4 all are local varible declared inside the onCLick listner

Comment: i have a timer method i want to dismiss the dialog when timer event is encounterd

Comment: @hemant Why don't you save dialog reference to a field instead of a local variable?

Comment: Can you explain this with the help of an example

Comment: – Warpzit you can see in my query above AlertDialog .setPositiveButton contains DailogInterface dailog, how this dailog can be passes as a refrence to dailog

Comment: You need to show more code then. Because the right procedure would simply be to give a field reference and then remove all non null dialogs in a method call.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31324/discussion-between-hemant-and-warpzit)

Comment: – Warpzit you can see in my code , same code is written for creating 4 alertbox , i want all of them to be removed at one glance